# Problems with active-trails

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks, routes

I have played with Menu Trail by Path and Menu Position, but none worked well with a Views-generated listing acting as a navigation menu.

Imagine the following scenario:

1. On the left side there is Views generated block of linked taxonomy terms.
2. When clicked, the link fills the main content area with a listing of nodes tagged with the given taxonomy term. The activated term link gets `active-trail` class - so far so good.
3. When you click a node link though, the node opens, but now - the `active-trail` is gone.

The complicating factor might be that my taxonomy is localized (each term has a translation within same vocabulary). But I believe there is a solution to that... Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that taxonomy is not a menu system, the menu system is.  There are ways to make the menu system mirror taxonomy, but they are separate systems.  [Taxonomy_menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) might be able to help.